# Python 3.3 Tkinter LabelFrame resizable

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Is it possible to create a resizable `LabelFrame`?
Or any way?
And is it possible to use `ttk.PanedWindow` with `LabelFrame` for this?

it's my code:

```
fram1 = ttk.LabelFrame(root, text = "text1", height = 100, width = 200)      
fram1.config(relief=FLAT)
fram1.pack(side = "right", fill="both", expand = True)

fram2 = ttk.LabelFrame(root, text = "text2", height = 100, width = 200)      
fram2.config(relief=FLAT)
fram2.pack(side = "left", fill="both", expand = True)
```

and i can't `resize` these `labelframes`

Comment: Yes, it's possible. If you are having problems making it work, show us your code and tell us the specific problem you're having.

Comment: Your question will be better if you put that information in the question. You can edit your own question by clicking on the edit link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The panedwindow can hold any single widget in a pane so a labelframe is no problem and allows you to add further widgets and children of the labelframe. An example:

```
import sys
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

def main():
    app = Tk()
    pw = PanedWindow(app, orient='vertical')
    paneA = LabelFrame(pw, text="Pane A", height=240, width=320)
    paneB = LabelFrame(pw, text="Pane B", height=240, width=320)
    pw.add(paneA, weight=50)
    pw.add(paneB, weight=50)
    pw.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
    app.mainloop()

if __name__=='__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

The weight allows you to set a proportionate scaling for each pane as you change the size of the container. If both panes have the same weight then they grow by the same amount.

Comment: yes its work thanks.
its better to use ttk.PanedWindow and ttk.LabelFrame.