# Nested Frame won't resize in outer frame

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am able to create the Frames as I want and add the widgets accordingly. However, when I try to resize the `homeframe` in the `StartPage` class it doesn't resize. I have tried the `.configure` as well. Neither seem to resize the `homeframe`. I have tried everything I know of to get the frame to resize and I have had no luck.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

LARGE_FONT = ("verdana", 12)

class tool(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        tk.Tk.iconbitmap(self, default="supporticon.ico")

        self.geometry("400x400")
        self.resizable(0,0)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, PageOne):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
            frame.config(bg="darkblue")
        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        homeframe = Frame(self, width=200, height=350)
        homeframe.config(background="darkblue")
        homeframe.pack()
        label = Label(homeframe, text="Start Page", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.config(background="darkblue", fg="white")
        label.pack()

        button1 = ttk.Button(homeframe, text="Vist Page 1",
                             command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button1.pack()

class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Page One", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()


app = tool()
app.resizabe=(0,0)
app.geometry=("450x450")
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Tkinter widgets are designed to shrink or grow to fit their contents. Why do you want it to be bigger than it needs to be? Usually if you want a frame to be bigger, the solution is to make the contents of the frame bigger.

Comment: The indentation is broken in your code example. Please try to fix it.

Comment: try adding more contents to make the frame bigger?

Comment: does this solve your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26202302/python-3-3-tkinter-labelframe-resizable?rq=1)

Comment: If you really want to see 'true' size of your homeframe widget, put under `homeframe.pack()` this line: `homeframe.pack_propagate(False)`. As Bryan said before your frame will change size according to its content, setting mentioned flag as false will turn off this functionality.